# Custom Screensaver?

Tags: mac, macos, system-settings, screensaver

In OS X El Capitan
Version 10.11.6

I am trying to set my custom Screensaver, i.e. my own picture and not the predefined ones, just like as one would do for the Desktop background.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `System Preferences > Desktop & Screen Saver > Screen Saver tab` and click the Snapshots item. Under the Source picker, you can choose any folder you desire using the `Choose Folder...` option:

[image]

Comment: This is a great tip. I've been trying to figure out how to use one static (dark) image as a screensaver. I did this, and I only put one image in the file. Works perfectly.

Comment: There is no "Snapshots" in my case. However, turns out that if I click to the "Floating", for example, icon, I have the option you mention ("Choose Folder").

Answer (score 1):

I also am on EL C 10.11.6 and was unable to set up my own screensaver. In fact none of the provided screensavers loaded either.
Took me a while to figure out that you must select one of the options (eg Ken Burns) from the left hand frame for it to work.